# Capybara / Rspec / FactoryGirl spec failing when the code does work as intended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

Having trouble with a rspec spec. The actual code seems to be working fine, but my spec is still failing. I'm using FactoryGirl, Rspec and Capybara. This is part of spec/features/admin/admin_users_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Admin::Users" do

  subject { page }

  context "When admin signed in" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before { sign_in admin }

    context "when visiting admin users" do

      before { visit admin_users_path }

      it_should_behave_like "admin visiting admin page"
      it { should have_content('- User Index') }
      it { should have_content(user.email) }  # This test is failing
    end
  end
end
```

The test that is failing has the comment.

Here is my factories for users.

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do
    email         { Faker::Internet.email }
    admin         false
    super_admin   false
    password      "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    confirmed_at  Time.now

    factory (:admin) do
      admin true
    end

    factory (:super_admin) do 
      admin true
      super_admin true
    end
  end
end
```

The idea that when you go to the index for users in the admin dashboard, admins should see a list of users. So in addition to the current admin, I create another user to populate the test database. Here is a sample failure message:

```
Failures:

  1) Admin::Users When admin signed in when visiting admin users should text "christian.stark@rempel.com"
     Failure/Error: it { should have_content(user.email) }
       expected to find text "christian.stark@rempel.com" in "Under The Gun Theater Admin Edit profile Logout Dashboard Users Posts Pages Shows Classes People Photos Admin Dashboard - User Index Email Roles Last Logged In geovanni.marks@kaulke.com admin May 18, 2014 11:59 Logged in as geovanni.marks@kaulke.com"
     # ./spec/features/admin/admin_users_spec.rb:53:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

As you can see, the table that is generated on the page only includes the admin's email address. The other user "christian.stark@rempel.com" is not found. Again, when I actually log into the app it works, so I'm not sure why this test is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `let!` instead of `let` for `user`.

`let` is **lazily evaluated**, that is, `user` won't come into existence till something is called upon it. `let!` helps out in sorting this issue by **eagerly evaluating** the block.

```
let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
```

Read more about [let and let!](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) here.

OR, you can `create` a user manually in `before` block as:

```
before do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  sign_in admin
end
#corresponding test:
it { should have_content(@user.email) }  # This test should pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Your user is not being created until after you've loaded the page. `let`s are lazy in RSpec. The user record gets created on this line:

```
it { should have_content(user.email) }
```

which will always fail since the user wasn't created before the time that the page was loaded. You can change `let(:user)` to `let!(:user)`, which will run it eagerly before the test. You might want to consider a different structure though, which helps avoid these issues:

```
admin = create(:user, :admin)
user = create(:user)

sign_in admin
visit admin_users_path

expect(page).to have_content('- User Index')
expect(page).to have_content(user.email)
```